# SQL Server Agent log is showing error [298] SQLServer Error: 16389, Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01] (LogToTableWrite)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

[image]While checking SQL Server Agent Log i found lot of error like follows

*[298] SQLServer Error: 16389, Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01] (LogToTableWrite)
[298] SQLServer Error: 10004, Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01] (LogToTableWrite)*

Anyone having idea about this error ? Is there any impact ? How we can resolve the same

Comment: Did you check SQL agent log file? It seems its not started successfully or there is some issue with msdb.

Comment: I vaguelly recall something similar with some RTM release. Could it have been 2012? Anyhow, make sure you aren't on RTM...